# Arduino hardwareSerial Bluetooth.println not sending string over 310 chars

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, softwareserial, arduino-leonardo, buffer

Hey all I am wondering if my code below can be modified in order for the Arduino to send more than 300 chars to a HM-10 bluetooth 4.0 le module?

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 512

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(8,9); // RX, TX
String btString;
String comString;
int isVS;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {;}

  Serial.println("PC Side Connected");

  bluetooth.begin(115200);
  while (!bluetooth) {;}

  bluetooth.println("Bluetooth Side Connected");
}

void loop() { 
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    //The IDE Sends and the phone receives
    comString = Serial.readString();

    //Check to see if this request is coming from Visual Studio
    isVS = comString.indexOf("_VS");

    if (isVS > -1) {
      //Is coming from Visual Studio so display it over serial port      
    } else {
      //Not coming from VS so send it to the bluetooth phone
      //bluetooth.write(comString);
      bluetooth.println(comString);
    }
  }

  if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
    //The phone sends and the IDE receives
    btString = bluetooth.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(btString);
  }
}
```

As in my code above, I've already tried to add the **#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 512** to the top to give the software serial more buffers but that does not allow me to send more than ~310 chars.

So sending this string:

> {MAC:'00-14-22-01-23-45',settings:{rgb:true,quotes:true,sleep:false,timeFrame:{on:'05:30:00',off:'22:30:00'},reset:false,weatherZip:'57104',userInfo:{left:'John
>   Rambo',right:'T100'}},wifiInfo:{Name:'ItBurnsWhenIP',Pwd:'AwHk6gKnsMdxw3boWWAhus5NNCV304YQb/2287QqzH0WnS5W59vCzzW2pR8kgHI79hAUglQOCcBiEKiNWRBQ3oyvyJ0/fDfM1aKa9gfoy3kGHA=='}}

works just fine but if i send out a little more information:

> {MAC:'00-14-22-01-23-45',settings:{rgb:true,quotes:true,sleep:false,timeFrame:{on:'05:30:00',off:'22:30:00'},reset:false,weatherZip:'57104',userInfo:{left:'JohnRambo',right:'T100'}},wifiInfo:{Name:'ItBurnsWhenIP',Pwd:'AwHk6gKnsMdxw3boWWAhus5NNCV304YQb/2287QqzH0WnS5W59vCzzW2pR8kgHI79hAUglQOCcBiEKiNWRBQ3oyvyJ0/fDfM1aKa9gfoy3kGHA==','testing
>   out some more strings'}}

It shows everything but the **gs'}}** at the end on the iphone.

How would i go about fixing this so i can send much more than this?

Comment: Re work it to not use String. The problem isn't serial, it's how you're storing the data.

Comment: Alright mind showing me an example?

Comment: You need to understand both these blog posts: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/ and https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/